# How to ignore an empty span

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of elements for a menu. This contains a item name, price, description and list of extras. If a description is left out the `span` it contains still fills up space even though it is empty. The description and extras CSS are the same class but can be changed if need be. This is being used in the bootstrap jumbotron.

**HTML**

```
<div id="item_124">
    <span class="left">Cheeseburger</span>
    <span class="right"> 2.50</span>
    <span class="center">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="description">Burger full o cheese</span>
    <span class="extras"><b>OPTIONS:</b> OP1, OP2, OP3, Onion, Cheese, Tomato, Bacon</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menuOutput .description, .extras{
    line-height: 7px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**Results**

- Current result

  > ```
  > Cheeseburger 2.50 
  > Burger full o cheese
  > OPTIONS: OP1, OP2, OP3, Onion, Cheese, Tomato, Bacon
  > ```
- Result with description omitted

  > ```
  > Cheeseburger 2.50 
  >  
  > OPTIONS: OP1, OP2, OP3, Onion, Cheese, Tomato, Bacon
  > ```
- Required result

  > ```
  > Cheeseburger 2.50
  > OPTIONS: OP1, OP2, OP3, Onion, Cheese, Tomato, Bacon
  > ```

Any suggestions to make the empty `span` not take up any space unless filled?

Comment: Could you setup a jsfiddle demo? Have you changed the default display type of the `span` elements?

Comment: Note that 'empty' and '&nbsp;' are two different things. Is the span empty, or does it have a non breaking space character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to exclude the empty `<span>` element from the selected elements, you could use a combination of [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) and [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aempty) pseudo classes to achieve that.

Something like:

```css
#menuOutput .description:not(:empty) { /* styles goes here... */ }
```

For instance:

```css
.description:not(:empty), .extras {
    background-color: gold;
    min-height: 20px;
}
```

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/qevas/1/edit)**.

It's worth noting that `:not()` and `:empty` pseudo classes [are supported in **IE9+**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).